# zend : populating a checkbox array with $form->populate(); from controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, checkbox, zend-form

We have a `zend` form with text input fields and array of checkboxes, as shown below -

```
<input class="checkbox_Category" type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="19"> somename1 <br/>
<input class="checkbox_Category" type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="20"> somename2 <br/>
<input class="checkbox_Category" type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="21"> somename3 <br/>
```

and using a

> $formObject->populate($formDataArray);

in the controller to populate data in the whole form. All the text input fields seem to populate fine, but the checkboxes don't. Int the $formDataArray, the data for the checkboxes is in the format

> [tag] => Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 19 )

Along with the other form data like - [firstName] => 'somename' etc.
I am not able to figure out the format of the data the form is expecting, in order to get populated with populate();

Comment: The format you have is correct, so the problem is not in the code you posted. If you tick some checkboxes and submit the form, missing a required field (so the form is redisplayed), do the checkboxes remain ticked?

Answer (score 0):

hi might be problem with the name you have given as array please change like below

```
<input class="checkbox_Category" type="checkbox" name="tag" value="19"> somename1 <br/>
<input class="checkbox_Category" type="checkbox" name="tag" value="20"> somename2 <br/>
<input class="checkbox_Category" type="checkbox" name="tag" value="21"> somename3 <br/>
```

Please let me know if i can help you further

Comment: Hi .. i am sure the array is required, because that is how we iterate and get the checked values ones posted.

Comment: but as i am using with zend form it is working fine for me like   $objEthnicity = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox("ethnicity");
    $objEthnicity ->addMultiOptions($ethnicity)
            ->setLabel($this->translate('LABEL_ETHNICITY')) 
            ->setValue(explode("#",$profileData['ethnicity']))
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')
    ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
    ->removeDecorator('Label')
        ->setAttrib("no","2");

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing your Zend_Form code, this is very difficult.  However, most often, I've seen people mistake the 'checkbox' element with the 'multiCheckbox' element in Zend Framework.  I know - it's a bit confusing - but checkbox is a single checkbox with an on/off value.  MultiCheckbox handles multiple values - and I think it's what you are trying to accomplish.  Let me show you a quick form that will work and generate your HTML above.

```
class Application_Form_Test extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $multiOptions = array(
            19 => 'somename1',
            20 => 'somename2',
            21 => 'somename3'
        );

        $this->addElement('multiCheckbox', 'tag', array(
            'multiOptions'=>$multiOptions
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'submitbutton');
    }
}
```

Now, if you use something like...

```
$form->populate($this->getRequest()->getPost());
```

in your controller, it will populate as expected.

Hope this helps!